# C# stop on null reference

Tags: c#, sql, try-catch, nullreferenceexception

during the login sequence of my program, I check for the existance of the user in the admin table

If they don't exist in the admin table, I want the program to then stop executing the rest of the login sequence and update a label text on the login screen to show why they cannot login etc...

At the moment the label doesn't update with the text and this would be down to refreshing the page before changing the text.

I also have other checks that occur during login that could stop them from logging in.

What would be the best approach in the case to ensure based on certain checks, a different label text can be displayed each time?

Thanks for your help

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    string checkAdmin = "Select Username from Admins where Username= '" + Session["Username"] + "'";

    SqlCommand adminCheck = new SqlCommand(checkAdmin, conn);
    string admin = adminCheck.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    conn.Close();
    Session["Admin"] = admin;
}
catch (NullReferenceException)
{

    Session.Abandon();
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    Label3.Text = "blablabla"
}
```

EDIT

OK I have updated it now based on your comments to....

```
                try
            {

                string checkAdmin = "Select Username from Admins where Username= @User";
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand adminCheck = new SqlCommand(checkAdmin, conn);
                adminCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", Session["Username"]);
                var admin = adminCheck.ExecuteScalar();
                conn.Close();
                if (admin != null)
                {
                    Session["Admin"] = admin;


                }

                else 
                {
                    Session["Admin"] = null;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
```

Comment: I (personally) wouldn't rely on a raised exception to invoke this behaviour with the UI

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And checking the count of the row that your query return sounds better instead check your first cell value if you _stop_ NullReferenceException. And catching NRE is not a good idea.

Comment: Do *not* make a habit of catching NullReferenceException. A NRE almost exclusively represents a logical error that should be fixed.

Comment: Another thing i think it is wrong is that you check Session["Username"] but store it in Session["Admin"]. Then the username will always be null

Comment: OP, am I right in thinking you've had this exception previously - and (due to the fact you think it's because of the response from the DB) you're attempting to handle it in this way? If so, post the line that raises this exception. You're using this try/catch to mask an error in your code as the comment above suggests and there's probably better (more defensive) ways of dealing with a user not existing.

Comment: string admin = adminCheck.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

When this runs, it returns null because the user doesn't exist in the DB and so its caught in the null reference exception.

Would be better to store a value and check for 1 or 0?

Comment: Your right, I have parameterized it now

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
> ```

This will immediately cancel the execution of the current code, and transfer to the that URL (presumably some other code). Therefore the following statement, to change the label, will not be executed.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4(v=vs.110).aspx) (remarks section):

> Redirect calls [End](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end(v=vs.110).aspx) which throws a ThreadAbortException exception upon completion.

Comment: Yep, that's correct, how can I stop execution of the rest of the page and just update the label text?

Comment: @DavidHayward I think you are misunderstanding how HTTP works, and how WebForms works within HTTP request/response cycle: until the page completes execution there will be no response to send to the client with the changed label.

Comment: HI Richard, I used return; in the end